# Filter for how many users made more than 5 failed deposits within a 10 minute timeframe

Tags: postgresql, window-functions

This query returns the number of failed deposits per user made within an hour timeframe. It only filters for 5 or more failed deposits.
However, now I need to filter only for users who have made 5 or more deposits within a 10 minute timeframe.
I don't know how do this.

```
with windowed_data as
    (
    select *,
       max(window_count) over (partition by user_id, transaction_window) as max_window_count
from (select
          *,
          COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY user_id, DATE_TRUNC('hour', created)  ORDER BY created) AS window_count,
          DATE_TRUNC('hour', created) AS transaction_window
      FROM source.payments2_transactions
      WHERE state = 'FAILED'
      and type = 'DEPOSIT'
      and country = 'PE'
      and created >= current_date - interval '120 days'
      and created < current_date + interval '1 day') wd)
select
    user_id,
    created,
    window_count,
    transaction_window,
    max_window_count
from windowed_data wd
where max_window_count >= 5
;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the following, where I revised the query now to target identifying users who have experienced 5 or more failed deposit transactions within any 10-minute window over the last 120 days, specifically for deposits in Peru. It achieves this by first calculating a '`transaction_window`' for each transaction, which aligns timestamps to the nearest 10-minute block.

```
WITH windowed_data AS (
    SELECT
        *,
        COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY user_id, transaction_window) AS window_count,
        transaction_window
    FROM (
        SELECT
            user_id,
            created,
            DATE_TRUNC('minute', created) - (EXTRACT(MINUTE FROM created)::integer % 10) * INTERVAL '1 minute' AS transaction_window,
            state
        FROM
            source.payments2_transactions
        WHERE
            state = 'FAILED'
            AND type = 'DEPOSIT'
            AND country = 'PE'
            AND created >= CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL '120 days'
            AND created < CURRENT_DATE + INTERVAL '1 day'
    ) AS subquery
),
aggregated_data AS (
    SELECT
        user_id,
        MAX(window_count) OVER (PARTITION BY user_id, transaction_window) AS max_window_count,
        transaction_window
    FROM
        windowed_data
)
SELECT
    user_id,
    transaction_window,
    max_window_count
FROM
    aggregated_data
WHERE
    max_window_count >= 5;
```